# How i can fix error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orderItems')?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-redux, action

i'm starting developing one webshop and i got this error.
This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./../components/Header";
import { PayPalButton } from "react-paypal-button-v2";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getOrderDetails } from "../Redux/Actions/OrderAction";
import Message from "../components/LoadingError/Error";
import Loading from "../components/LoadingError/Loading";
import moment from "moment/moment";

const OrderScreen = ({match}) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  const orderId = match.params.id;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;



  if (!loading && order && order.orderItems) {
    const addDecimals = (num) => {
      return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    };
  
    order.itemsPrice = addDecimals(
      order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId))
  },[dispatch, orderId,order])
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        {
          loading ? (<Loading/>) : error ? (<Message variant="alert-danger">{error}</Message>) :
          (
            <>
                    <div className="row  order-detail">
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-lg-4 mb-5 mb-sm-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4 center">
                <div className="alert-success order-box">
                  <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-8 center">
                <h5>
                  <strong>Customer</strong>
                </h5>
                <p>{order.user.name}</p>
                <p>
                  <a href={`mailto:${order.user.email}`}>{order.user.email}</a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* 2 */}
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-lg-4 mb-5 mb-sm-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4 center">
                <div className="alert-success order-box">
                  <i className="fas fa-truck-moving"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-8 center">
                <h5>
                  <strong>Order info</strong>
                </h5>
                <p>Shipping: {order.shippingAddress.country}</p>
                <p>Pay method: {order.paymentMethod}</p>
                {order.isPaid ? (
                    <div className="bg-info p-2 col-12">
                    <p className="text-white text-center text-sm-start">
                      Paid on {moment(order.paidAt).calendar()}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  )
                  :
                  (
                    <div className="bg-danger p-2 col-12">
                    <p className="text-white text-center text-sm-start">
                      Not Paid
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* 3 */}
          <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 mb-lg-4 mb-5 mb-sm-0">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4 center">
                <div className="alert-success order-box">
                  <i className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-8 center">
                <h5>
                  <strong>Deliver to</strong>
                </h5>
                <p>
                  Address: {order.shippingAddress.city},{" "}
                  {order.shippingAddress.address},{" "}
                  {order.shippingAddress.postalCode}
                </p>
                {order.isDelivered ? (
                    <div className="bg-info p-2 col-12">
                    <p className="text-white text-center text-sm-start">
                      Delivered on {moment(order.deliveredAt).calendar()}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  )
                  :
                  (
                    <div className="bg-danger p-2 col-12">
                    <p className="text-white text-center text-sm-start">
                      Not Delivered
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row order-products justify-content-between">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            {
              order.orderItems.length === 0 ? (
                <Message variant="alert-info mt-5">Your order is empty</Message>
              ) 
              :
              (
                <>
                {
                  order.orderItems.map((item,index) => (
                    <div className="order-product row" key={index}>
                    <div className="col-md-3 col-6">
                      <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-5 col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
                      <Link to={`/products/${item.product}`}>
                        <h6>{item.name}</h6>
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-3 mt-md-0 col-md-2 col-6  d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center ">
                      <h4>QUANTITY</h4>
                      <h6>{item.qty}</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-3 mt-md-0 col-md-2 col-6 align-items-end  d-flex flex-column justify-content-center ">
                      <h4>SUBTOTAL</h4>
                      <h6>${item.qty * item.price}</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  ))}
                </>
              )
            }
            {/* <Message variant="alert-info mt-5">Your order is empty</Message> */}
          </div>
          {/* total */}
          <div className="col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-end flex-column mt-5 subtotal-order">
            <table className="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Products</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>${order.itemsPrice}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Shipping</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>${order.shippingPrice}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Tax</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>${order.taxPrice}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Total</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>${order.totalPrice}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="col-12">
              <PayPalButton amount={345} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </>
);
      };

export default OrderScreen;
```

And i become this error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orderItems')"
I'm developing this project with Redux, axios and React.

Here is code from OrderAction

```
import {
  ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
  ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST,
  ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
  ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  ORDER_LIST_MY_FAIL,
  ORDER_LIST_MY_REQUEST,
  ORDER_LIST_MY_SUCCESS,
  ORDER_PAY_FAIL,
  ORDER_PAY_REQUEST,
  ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS,
} from "../Constants/OrderConstants";
import axios from "axios";
import { CART_CLEAR_ITEMS } from "../Constants/CartConstants";
import { logout } from "./userActions";

// CREATE ORDER
export const createOrder = (order) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/orders`, order, config);
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    dispatch({ type: CART_CLEAR_ITEMS, payload: data });

    localStorage.removeItem("cartItems");
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === "Not authorized, token failed") {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};

// ORDER DETAILS
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${id}`, config);
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === "Not authorized, token failed") {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};

// ORDER PAY
export const payOrder =
  (orderId, paymentResult) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_REQUEST });

      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = getState();

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      };

      const { data } = await axios.put(
        `/api/orders/${orderId}/pay`,
        paymentResult,
        config
      );
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      if (message === "Not authorized, token failed") {
        dispatch(logout());
      }
      dispatch({
        type: ORDER_PAY_FAIL,
        payload: message,
      });
    }
  };

// USER ORDERS
export const listMyOrders = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_LIST_MY_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/`, config);
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_LIST_MY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === "Not authorized, token failed") {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_LIST_MY_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};
```

In this file are actions which i´m doing with Orders, i think problem also can be here.

Answer (score 0):

By the `orderItems` being undefined that means the `order` is as well.

You could check so that both aren't undefined by using conditional statement.

```js
if (!loading && order && order.orderItems) {
  const addDecimals = (num) => {
    return (Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  };

  order.itemsPrice = addDecimals(
    order.orderItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
  );
}
```

That will make sure that both the `order` and the `orderItems` are defined before trying to access them.

Update :

You got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"`

To fix it you can add :

```js
{!loading && order && order.user && (
  <p>{order.user.name}</p>
)}
```

It will basically do the same as above but in your jsx

Comment: now i get error:"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
Maybe its problem somewhere in another place?

Comment: Line? Where? its just name or in a object?

Comment: <p>{order.user.name}</p> in this line

Comment: its because the container is only lookin at "loading" and doesn't care if the order is there. So you can update the condition and it should work

Comment: Can you give an example how i should update it?